# Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code

Tags: apt, dpkg

When trying to install phpmyadmin on my Ubuntu instance, I accidentally quit the job midway through.

Now I can't continue it/remove it to start again..

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
phpmyadmin is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0B/4,342kB of archives.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Selecting previously deselected package phpmyadmin.
(Reading database ... 38239 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace phpmyadmin 4:3.3.7-5build0.10.10.1 (using .../phpmyadmin_4%3a3.3.7-5build0.10.10.1_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement phpmyadmin ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: warning: subprocess old post-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg - trying script from the new package instead ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/phpmyadmin_4%3a3.3.7-5build0.10.10.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new post-removal script returned error exit status 1
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess new post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/phpmyadmin_4%3a3.3.7-5build0.10.10.1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can anyone shed any light? Not sure what to do, seems I need to remove the lock, delete the files(?) and restart the install?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the process ID here:

```
fuser -v /var/cache/debconf/config.dat
```

Then kill the pid:

```
sudo kill ###
```

Then run this:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Sesh on.